# Finding the 5th result of a search bar using selenium,python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a web scraper using selenium and Python and would like to find the 5th result of the search that appears on the webpage (a dog).

I have successfully written the code for doing the search. However, I'm not sure how to make the scraper click on the 5th link.

You can find my code below. I'd love any help!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from PIL import Image

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("dog")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(0.5)

#getting the 5 result for the search
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a/h3')
results[4].click()
```

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: Hi, scraping google directly is not a great idea imho because they catch you right away. 
Try take a look at this library: https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper

Comment: It is originally an assignment,  to I have to do  it this way. there is no error when i run the code, or no error to my knowledge as because i am fairly new to selenium and am not too clear about its functions.my issue is that i cant code it to click on the nth result of my search, if you have any suggestions or questions i could try to explain it to you further or show you the assignemnt i have been tasked with directly, thanks for your reply. @Wonka

Comment: @AlessandroTogni i had a look at the link you sent , thanks for the suggestion but i dont think this is what my assignemnt is looking for , but thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hey Krisha, I understand that you're confused about why your code isn't working. However, Stack Overflow isn't a homework-solving website. We can help with your code, but your problem has to be specific. If you add the following details to your question, you'll get a better response. What EXACTLY happens when you run your code? What webpage are you trying to scrape? What exactly is the 5th link on the page? How have you tried to solve the issue?

If this sounds like a lot of work, that's because debugging code takes time and effort, and we can only help if you give us details.